# Lower and upper bounds of the distance between two Frobenius numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, linear-algebra, finite-groups

**I consider two sequences of numbers:** $A=\{a_1,...,a_{m-1},n\}$ and $B=\{n-a_{m-1},...,n-a_1,n\}$, where $a_1 < a_2 < ... < a_{m-1} < n$ and $\gcd(A) = \gcd(B) = 1$.

---

**I investigate the lower and upper bounds of the distance between two Frobenius Numbers:**

$ Dist Lower Bound \le \left| F(A) - F(B) \right| \le Dist Upper Bound $

**I found only one trivial estimate for lower bound:**
It is known that $F(a_1,...,a_m) \ge a_1 - 1$ if $a_1 \ge 2$.
Using this property, we obtain that:

$\left| F(A) - F(B) \right| \ge \left| n-a_{m-1}-a_1 \right|$.

---

**Also, I investigate the lower and upper bounds of the sum of two Frobenius Numbers:**

$ Sum Lower Bound \le F(A) + F(B) \le Sum Upper Bound $

**I found only one trivial estimate for upper bound:**
I am using simple way. I took well-known estimates and combine it because I having knowledge about $a_{m-1}$.

$1. F(a_1,...,a_m) \le 2a_{m-1} \lfloor{\frac{a_m}{m}}\rfloor - a_m = 2a_{m-1} \lfloor{\frac{n}{m}}\rfloor - n$.

$2. F(b_1,...,b_m) \le 2b_m \lfloor{\frac{b_1}{m}}\rfloor - b_1 = 2n \lfloor{\frac{n-a_{m-1}}{m}}\rfloor - n + a_{m-1}$.

---

**I am convinced that there are other nearer solutions. I will be grateful for any help in search $ Sum Lower Bound $ and $ Dist Upper Bound $ as well as improving my estimates.**

About Frobenius Number can be read here: [link 1](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FrobeniusNumber.html), [link 2](http://www.thefullwiki.org/Frobenius_number#cite_note-ramirez-0).

Comment: Also posted in math.stackexchange: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3262435/lower-and-upper-bounds-of-the-distance-between-two-frobenius-numbers

Comment: It is frowned upon to post identical questions near simultaneously on both sites.  Here, you waited 25 minutes between postings. You should pick one site (whichever it seems appropriate for), and then await for responses. It prevents duplication of effort. Please pick one, and delete the other; you can undelete it later if the site you pick does not end up being appropriate. Same comment will be placed in math.stackexchange.